# In any triangle the angle opposite the greater side is greater.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a small problem with the following :
http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI18.html

I did understand the proof, but the proposition claims that the angle opposite the greater side is greater and Euclid only proves that it is greater than one other angle. (angle ABC is greater than ACB)

Am I supposed to understand that I must prove for the other case by myself? (I fill in the details ?) OR I didn't understand at all ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you understood the proof. The proof is a general case where $AC$ greater than $AB$. You can place the sides $AC$ and $AB$ anywhere in the picture. For example, switching the letters $A$ and $C$ in the picture, you get the proof of another pair. And notice the proof does not depend on the position of the letters.

Comment: Ok, so If I understood correctly, Euclid is writing the proof for only one pair (Like I said) By the way, Euclid assumes that AC is bigger than AB, but shouldn't we prove that it's also bigger than BC ?

Comment: That is what I said. It depends on how you draw the picture. If you draw it with $A$ on the current position of $C$, $C$ on the current position of $A$. Now with your new picture, read the proof again (DO NOT look at your original picture any more), see if it fits.

Comment: Ok, yes, it works. I don'T know why I didn't notice this. ANd what about my other question, should we just assume that AC is always bigger than the two other sides ?

Comment: It again depends on how you draw the picture and how you name the vertices with letters. You can name the longer side with BC, Then in the proof, just switch all the letters accordingly. It is a proof for any two sides in a triangle, with one side greater than another. Just use the letter $AC$ to represent the longer side.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm clear in my question. What I meant is, shouldn't we prove that AC, BC, or whatever it is named, is bigger than the others sides ? (Maybe I'm not just following you, sorry again and thanks for your patience)

Comment: I don't quite understand your question then. I think it is assumed that $AC$ is bigger than one of the other sides. So why do we need to prove?

Comment: Or if I understand correctly, you might have confused "greater" with "greatest". It assumes $AC$ is greater than another side. It does not have to be the longest side. So this argument also works for $AB$ and $BC$ in the original picture.

Comment: Oh ok, this proposition isn't for CA the greatest. (English isn't my first language) So, with this new understanding of the proposition, from what I understand it says that if we have a side that is greater than another one, than the angle opposite the greater side is always going to be greater than other angle. Is this how I'm supposed to understand it (I'm new to proofs)

Comment: No, to be frank, I don't understand what the theorem is saying...

Comment: Yes, it means in a triangle, between any  two sides, if one is greater than the other, then the angle opposite to it is greater than the angle opposite to the shorter side.

Comment: Yes, I finally got to understand it. I didn't read correctly what the proposition was saying and I was kind've tired. thanks